# Python Dict: Find key in a dictionary list

Tags: python, dictionary

i have dictionary which looks in following way

```
{
"modules": [
    {
        "outputs": {
            "AdminAZ1": "value1", 
            "AdminAZ2": "value2", 
            "Region": "value3"
       }
    }]
 }
```

my question i need to find the key "outputs" and return true

if it is true  need an output in the following way

```
"outputs": {
            "AdminAZ1": "value1", 
            "AdminAZ2": "value2", 
            "Region": "value3"
       }
```

Comment: Post what you tried already! And in what manner all your dictionaries will be similar to this one - dict with only one key and a list as value?

Comment: Please post a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can help you.

Comment: i tried using dict.has_key('outputs') it returned false since it is in list

Comment: will `dict["modules"][0].has_key('outputs')` always work?

Comment: i am aware of using dict['modules'][0] but the key 'modules' in my case will be changing dynamically every time, is there is a way to find a string using regular expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should help you

```
dict ={
"modules": [
    {
        "outputs": {
            "AdminAZ1": "value1",
            "AdminAZ2": "value2",
            "AWSRegion": "value6"
       }
    }]
 }
#check if outputs is present
print reduce(lambda x,y: x or y, map(lambda x: "outputs" in x.keys(),dict["modules"]), False)
#return outputs if present
print reduce(lambda x,y: x if x else y, map(lambda x: x["outputs"] if "outputs" in x.keys() else None,dict["modules"]), None)
```

Comment: Now that's a truly lovely way to do it. :-)

Comment: updated the answer to also return the value of outputs

Answer (score 0):

```
mydict={
"modules": [
{
    "outputs": {
        "AdminAZ1": "value1", 
        "AdminAZ2": "value2", 
        "Region": "value3"
   }
}]}

result = mydict[mydict.keys()[0]][0]
if "outputs" in result:
    print result
```

Result:

```
{
    "outputs": {
        "AdminAZ1": "value1", 
        "AdminAZ2": "value2", 
        "Region": "value3"
   }
```